# How to detect Android browser hide soft-keyboard event?

Tags: javascript, android, soft-keyboard

I have a problem with **Android Webkit browser** and must detect when the soft-keyboard is hidden by hand(pressing the button on the right top).

[image]

Like in the above picture, when I press the button, the soft keyboard will be hidden but no `resize` event is triggered. Nor the input is blured. I also found that the `document.body.clientHeight` is not changed. So how should I detect this action?

Thanks!

Comment: Which element are you attaching the resize event handler to? I can see `document.body.onresize` triggers the event on opening/collapsing of the keyboard as well as the address bar. In the past I would add a 1px div with `opacity:0` and `pointer-events: none` that is positioned absolutely to `bottom:0` and record its offset on page load (i.e. the keyboard is always collapsed when page first loads). When the resize event is triggered I check what the current offset of that div is and if it matches the original offset then I know that the on-screen keyboard was just collapsed.

Comment: Thank you for that, @MattNewelski , clever job. I want to hide a bottom nav bar, which did not show in this picture.

Answer (score 2):

So this was my solution to get around this issue:

First I ran a function to detect which mobile device was being used:

```
var getMobileOperatingSystem = function() {
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
    if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
        return "Android";
    }
};
if (getMobileOperatingSystem() === 'Android') {
    // REST OF CODE
}
```

When the android keyboard is open this changes the value of window.innerHeight. 
 Because of this I created a function which when called would continuously run every 500ms, each time retrieving the height of the devices window and storing it in a variable.  I also created another variable which would get the devices height when the page has loaded.  Once these two variables values matched each other this indicated to me the keyboard had been hidden.

Here's the full code:

```
var getMobileOperatingSystem = function() {

    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

    if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
        return "Android";
    }

};

if (getMobileOperatingSystem() === 'Android') {

    var windowHeight;
    var originalHeight = window.innerHeight;

    var whenWindowHeightChanges = function(callback) {

        console.log(windowHeight, 'current window height');
        console.log(originalHeight, 'original window height');

        if (windowHeight === originalHeight) {
            if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                callback();
            }
        } else {
            setTimeout(function(){
                windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
                whenWindowHeightChanges(callback);
            }, 500);
        }
    }

    var input = $('footer input');

    input.on('focus', function(){

        whenWindowHeightChanges(function(){
            console.log('conditions passed');
            // CODE TO RUN WHEN ANDROID KEYBOARD IS HIDDEN
            windowHeight = null;
            input.blur();
        });     

    });

}
```